How can I get final hex color in Javascript from a relative CSS color string?
Let's say I have a CSS like that, which uses CSS Relative Colors syntax:
.my-element {
  color: rgb(from #aabbcc calc(r + 30) g calc(b - 30) / 80%);
}

(Updated to the correct syntax according to the comments below)
(in real life, this example would use CSS variables which I know how to substitute with actual values, so I simplified it).
In CSS it calculates a color with increased red and decreased blue channels, and with 80% alpha-channel.
I need to get that color and further manipulate it in my JS. Tried using getComputedStyle - it doesn't help, just returns the initial string representation of the color.
So, is there a way to get that final color in JS? Any built-in solution or a library?

All the code I have seen are focused on the element to which a css class has been applied, not the css class itself. have you searched for libraries created to manipulate css files?

to start with, the syntax is not correct. It should be color: rgb(from #aabbcc calc(r + 30) g calc(b - 30) / 80%)

As mentioned by @temani-afif, the correct syntax is:
.my-element {
    color: rgb(from #aaaaaa calc(r + 30) g calc(b - 30) / 80%);
}

Then, to get the computed color, you can use getComputedStyle (I changed #aabbcc to #aaaaaa for better representation):


const element = document.querySelector('.my-element');
const computedStyle = getComputedStyle(element);
const color = computedStyle.color;
console.log(color);
.my-element {
  color: rgb(from #aaaaaa calc(r + 30) g calc(b - 30) / 80%);
}
<div class="my-element">Some Text</div>



Additionally, if you want to convert that to rgba:


function srgbToRgb(srgb) {
  const match = srgb.match(/^color\(srgb\s+(.+?)\s+(.+?)\s+(.+?)\s+\/\s+(.+?)\)$/);
  if (!match) {
    throw new Error('Invalid srgb color');
  }
  const r = Math.round(parseFloat(match[1]) * 255);
  const g = Math.round(parseFloat(match[2]) * 255);
  const b = Math.round(parseFloat(match[3]) * 255);
  const a = parseFloat(match[4]);
  return `rgba(${r}, ${g}, ${b}, ${a})`;
}

const element = document.querySelector('.my-element');
const computedStyle = getComputedStyle(element);
const color = computedStyle.color;
console.log(srgbToRgb(color));
.my-element {
  color: rgb(from #aaaaaa calc(r + 30) g calc(b - 30) / 80%);
}
<div class="my-element">Some Text</div>




Thank you for the fast answer, this certainly helps!
Now I figured out what was wrong in my actual case, non-simplified. I didn't assign that value to the actual color property, but kept it in a CSS variable. Then tried to read that variable directly, like this: document.body.style.setProperty('--test-color', 'rgb(from #aaaaaa calc(r + 30) g calc(b - 30) / 80%)'); getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--test-color').
This returns the raw value, the final color is not computed. Apparently, getComputedStyle doesn't work for CSS variables. Any suggestions for that?

I couldn't reproduce that. See this codepen as an example.

I meant like that, reading variable value directly: https://codepen.io/AGrinko/pen/PoMZZwX
I'm guessing that is expected behavior and there is no way to force CSS into calculating that final color in a variable, before assigning it to a corresponding property like color.

Oh, I see. Yes, the reason is that you have not assigned the variable to anything as you said. A workaround could be to assign it to a dummy element and read the CSS from that.
